# Double integral with unknown exponents

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem is:

> Compute $$I = \iint _G \frac{1}{(1+3x^2+6xy+5y^2)^\alpha}\,dx\,dy$$
> for $\alpha > 2$ and $G =\{ (x,y): -y \leq x \leq y  \}$.

I have already tried plotting some examples to visualize. But it's still to hard and I do not know what to do, and how to do this calculations.

Comment: Perhaps you're meant to convert to polar coordinates?

Comment: Greg, I guess this could work, but how does I change the integration interval since it is an inproper integral (as long as I could figure it out)?

Comment: If we name the coordinates $r$ and $\theta$: what are all the values of $r$ that show up anywhere in $G$? then, for a given value of $r$, what values of $\theta$ show up in $G$ for that $r$? (Or reverse the roles of the two variables, depending on which order you want to integrate in.)